# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

The Route:

```
Route::get('test', array('before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'asd', function()
{
$user = User::find('1');               //Auth::user();
$user->Persona->last_name = 'Blaine';
$user->push();
print_r($user->Persona);
exit;
}));
```

The User Model:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected   $table          = 'ucpm_users';
    public function Persona()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Persona','persona');
    }
```

The Persona Model:

```
class Persona extends Eloquent 
{

protected   $table          = 'metadata_personas';

public function User()
{
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'persona');
}

public function Telefonos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Telefonos', 'persona');
}

}
```

When i Push() the entry model, Laravel trow a ErrorException:

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Support\Collection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line 41 and defined

The entry script (models and Route) are fully working under laravel3, i dont know why this dont work under Laravel4. Any help?

Comment: Wich one is the line 41?

Comment: public static function make($items)
 {
  if ($items instanceof Collection) return $items;

  return new static($items);
 }

Comment: Sorry I just asked the wrong question. Wich one (from your source code) is calling Collection::__construct()? Take a look at Whoops! stack list, once you get used to it is easy to find.

Comment: i dont see the stack list, the error come in json format on the request as i posted here =/ but if i remove the $user->push() its responce TRUE without any error (and without saving the data).

Comment: from the Apaches Logs: #0 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(26): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/var/www/larave...', 26, Array)
#1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(41): Illuminate\Support\Collection->__construct(Object(Persona))
#2 /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(5618): Illuminate\Support\Collection::make(Object(Persona))

#3 /var/www/laravel/app/modules/ucpm/routes/jsonSetterApi.php(62): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->push()

Comment: Error is happening while saving ($user->push()) all your User relationships. Take a look at them, they might be a little different en L4, for example, I'm not sure what you mean with `$this->belongsTo('Persona','persona')->with('User');` if you are already on your User model do you still need it?

Comment: i removed this part and "clearify" my models and routes. i updated the main posts with the new ones but i can´t solve this issue =/

Comment: I don't have any suggestions, but I have come across this problem as well.. I am trying to 'push' my User model, with related information, and getting an error at the same place. All I can tell is that push function calls "Collection::make" and passes in the 'relations' of the given model, which is fine, except Collection::make goes and tries to call a constructor with an object instead of an array which it's apparently looking for.. so not too sure.. seems like a bug in  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php.

Comment: It looks like we're not alone. Here is a reference to the bug in Laravel's 'issues' section https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1542

Comment: Solved in the new update [dbcbba1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah as I was alluding to in my comment, it was a bug with Laravel. Fortunately Taylor just posted a fix to it on github. Here is the commit:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/f41b86018cd3dc09dd5b216e98c3bfabf0653954

Essentially you just need to change line 41 in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php to say

```
    return new static(is_array($items) ? $items : array($items));
```

That should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing this issue myself I found that the answer give by John works, but requires files created by `composer` to be modified, which I don't think is an final solution.

[Garbee](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/414#issuecomment-220004890) suggested that what's actually required is to copy the `config` folder within `vendor/laralve/lumen-framework` into the root folder

> You have to create the folder in the app and copy any configs you need to modify from the framework package into it.

Doing this resolved my issues.